# bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer method causes blender to crash and slow down

Tags: python

in the code block below i wanted to show the number of vertex of the selected object on the screen.

```
import bpy
import blf

def draw_callback_3d(self, context):
    font_id = 0  # Default font
    blf.position(font_id, 150, 50, 0)  # Set the position of the text
    blf.size(font_id, 20, 72)  # Set the font size
    
    # Get the desired information to display
    vertex_count = len(bpy.context.active_object.data.vertices)
    
    # Display the information
    blf.draw(font_id, f"Vertex Count: {vertex_count}")

def update_callback(scene):
    bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=0.1)
    print('update_callback')

# Register the draw callback
def register_callback():
    args = (None, bpy.context)
    bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback_3d, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(update_callback)

# Unregister the draw callback
def unregister_callback():
    bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(draw_callback_3d, 'WINDOW')
    bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.remove(update_callback)

# Call the functions to register/unregister the HUD text overlay
register_callback()
# unregister_callback()
```

bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer method causes blender to crash and slow down. how can we solve this? iterations parameter is normally integer. but when I enter a float value like 0.1, the problem seems to improve. is there a stable solution for this? because it gives a lot of error messages to the console because 0.1 is float. what is the correct usage?

I am just trying use of HUD. no need any statics option about selected object.
just wantto show "hello world. hey selected object is just now changed". or something like this. why iterations parameter causes blender3d crash ? why iterations=0.1 just works even it should be an integer value... why ?

Comment: Hello. You can get rid of the `update_callback` function, can't you ?

Comment: so... if I remove update_callback.. how can I update text whenever needed ?
you mean update_callback is buggy?

Comment: I mean it doesn't serve any purpose whatsoever in your case, the text will be drawn anyways if you remove these lines